# Springboot test differences between findByID and findBy<Field>

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have a simple Springboot test like this:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void isVerifyingToken() throws Exception
{
  UserAccount user= new UserAccount("testName2", "PlainPassword", "test2@mail.com");

  mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(....... //here a controller function that changes the value of the field is enabled
        
 
  assertTrue(service.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).get(0).isEnabled());
  assertTrue(service.findById(user.getId()).isEnabled());
        
}
```

When I call the perform method that changes the value of the field retrived by isEnabled() i have the following situations:

- calling finByUsername I get the old status of the field
- calling findById I get the updated status of the field.

I have no idea about the motivations of this behaviour.

Update: screen of the DB as requested:

[image: Screen of the DB]

Edit: the method updating the DB:

```
@Transactional
public boolean checkToken(String token) throws UserAccountAlreadyVerified
{
  SecureToken sec= secureTokenService.findByToken(token).get(0);
  if( sec.getExpireAt().after(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now())))
  {
     UserAccount user=this.findById(sec.getId().getTokenId());
     if(!user.isEnabled() && !sec.isConsumed())
     {
         secureTokenService.consumeToken(sec);
         secureTokenService.save(sec);
         Hibernate.initialize(user);
         user.setEnabled(true);             
         this.save(user);
         return true;
     }
     else throw new UserAccountAlreadyVerified(sec.getToken());
  }
  return false;
}
```

Update: I'm using fetch strategy LAZY.

Comment: can you share all the data in db?

Comment: I added a screen, notiche the the testing account has the ID 4

Answer (score 0):

Can you also share the method updating the user state. Would like to know what annotations you are using there.

In any case, assuming you have `@Modifying` annotation on the update method for the repository, change it to `@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)`. Just a hunch.

As for the test, can you also try to reverse the order of assertions

```
assertTrue(service.findById(user.getId()).isEnabled());
assertTrue(service.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).get(0).isEnabled());
```

This is to check if it behaves in a similar fashion

Comment: I'm using only @Transactional. No matter the order of the two assertions

Comment: Not in the test.. but during the life cycle you mentioned something is updating that field. Whats that method and what annotation’s does it have.. thats what i want to know

Comment: I added in the question the method performing the modification.